# ItemTouchHelper looses drag state when notifying adapter

Tags: android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop, itemtouchhelper

I implemented a drag n drop by `recyclerview` and `ItemTouchHelper`.

I want to apply some changes when drag starts. So I'll notify adapter when `onSelectedChanged` gets `ACTION_STATE_DRAG`.

Notifying adapter just rebind items. It doesn't move items or add/remove item.

```
class ImageMoveCallback() : ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {
    override fun getMovementFlags(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Int =
        makeMovementFlags(RIGHT or LEFT or UP or DOWN, 0)

    override fun isLongPressDragEnabled(): Boolean = true
    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        // ...
        return true
    }

    override fun onSelectedChanged(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, actionState: Int) {
        super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState)
        if (actionState == ACTION_STATE_DRAG) {
           // notifying adapter
        }
    }

    override fun clearView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder)
        // ...
    }

    override fun isItemViewSwipeEnabled(): Boolean = false
    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {}
}
```

But when adapter notifies, drag State will be lost. And I get `ACTION_STATE_IDLE` in  `onSelectedChanged` and then `clearView` calls.

**Is it normal to loose drag state when I notifying adapter?**

**How can I do this?**